# Pain with the Overhead Press

Tags: weightlifting, pain

I have recently started doing the overhead press as per [Starting Strength](http://www.startingstrength.net/).

I am getting a pain when I get close to the full extension of the press. It *feels* like a tendon pain as it is in a very small area at the top of the shoulder joint.

The pain only occurs if I press more than about 30kg or so.

What could be causing that pain?

Or if its not that easy to tell over the internet what is causing the pain, what steps should I go through to try to locate and fix the cause?

Comment: You need to work on your rotator cuffs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssH35JwmwTM

Answer (score 3):

Shoulders are not to be f'd with.

Find a lifting coach and have them take a look at your form. You could find them at a local Olympic or powerlifting gym, CrossFit box, or a well-recommended personal trainer. Make sure they know Starting Strength and how to overhead press **before** you let them tell you how to do it. Pay them for a private lesson if necessary. Your shoulder health is well worth the fifty bucks or so.

You might also want to look into your shoulder mobility generally. You can try to self-diagnose by searching places like [Kelly Starrett's site](http://www.mobilitywod.com) and [gymnastics forums](http://gymnasticbodies.com/forum/), but in-person evaluations are again king.